# ios device cannot install addhoc version

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, device

I have a really annoying issue, I have a xcode Project that I needed to copy and make some Changes to (only some text Changes), so I started of by copying the whole Project and Place it in a Another folder on my mac, I then created an new provisioning profile and a new App ID, selected all the exsisting devices and downloaded the profiles, doubleclicked on them and then compiled the Project. The app can be installed on my ipad, but when I try with Another ipad (that was selected in devices) it give me an error saying this device isn't allowed to install the app... What could be wrong...?

Comment: Did you change old profiles in your projects built settings (code signing) with new profiles? Did you clean and restart the XCode? Can you add exact error message you received?

Comment: yes I change to the new profiles, did a clean and restarted Xcode. But it did not help, I checked with the id of the profiles in the member centre and selected those in build settings, but no...

Answer (score 0):

I hate the Member Center for reasons like this. Seriously, the best thing you can do is to delete everything (except for AppID) and start fresh.

**UPDATE**

For a clean start:

1. Delete all certificates and provisioning profiles
2. Re-create your certificates, provisioning profiles
3. Import them into your project/refresh code signing/refresh team
4. Build Settings > Code Signing: Set your **Code Signing Identity** & **Provisioning Profile** attributes
5. Select "iOS Devices", your schema, and then **Archive**

Last note pertinent to your specific issue: Make sure you are creating an **Ad Hoc** provisioning profile and archiving (& distributing) under that profile. I know how dee-d-dee this sounds, but it happens when you're not paying attention ;)

Comment: I can't say that I'm to happy about it either, if I should go with your proposal what is it I should delete for a clean start?

Comment: Hi, I only tried to delete the provisioning profiles and then regenerate them, and then set the code signing identity and the provisioning profiles, but that did not help. I didn't deleted the certificates, I'm afraid I will mess the other project I have thats working…By the way, I use testflight so that the users can install the app on their devices, is their maybe another way to get this to work without this issues with devices not allow to install the app?

Comment: You need to follow every step of the process. It's very important. No, this is unavoidable if you want to be able to distribute ad hoc builds

Comment: I have tried to distribute using testflight which did not work, but when i instead used www.diawi.com for the same thing, but also providing the add hoc provisioning profile it worked just fine. I still don't know why, but it works and thats what matters the most right now.